# Custom HttpHandler to block downloads of .wmv files

Tags: .net, asp.net, silverlight, http

I create a custom http handler to block download of .wmv files e.g. www.pakdev.net/videos/file.wmv (blocked by httpHandler).

But the problem is that now silverlight cannot also stream these video files as they are blocked too.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Use the WCF authentication services from silverlight to authenticate the user.  And then modify your custom http handler to allow downloads if the user is authenticated :-)